# += Operator in reflector?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, reflector

Im trying to find the `+=` in `reflector` in order to see how they implemented  :

`a=+1` vs `a=a+1`

but I cant find it.

any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no implemetation for the `+=` operator anywhere, it's a pseudo operator that is handled by the compiler. The C# compiler expands `a += 1` into `a = a + 1`.

The JIT compiler then creates the most efficient code to do the `a = a + 1`. If it's a simple variable it will just be an instruction that increases the value.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It can be, but this kind of code is always optimised to some degree. The optimize code switch is more about the relation between operations and how storage is handled. If this operation is done in a loop for example, with the optimize switch on the code might read the `a` variable into a register before the loop, hold the state in the register during the loop, and write it back to the variable after the loop. With the switch off, the value is always read and written for each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the `+=` for `int` and the other built-in numerical types: there won't be a library function to look at. The compiler can translate them directly into IL instructions.

You could try the `DateTime` struct, and maybe `Decimal` as well.

Comment: hi henk , does all base types dont appears in reflector ( and being translated directly by the compiler ) ?

Comment: henk not datetime nor decimal contain +=.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, ou can't overload `+=` in C#, but it can work anyway. `decimal d = 1m; d += 1m;` works fine.

Comment: "does all base types don't appears in reflector" - Not exactly, I think you should be able to find Int32.ToString() somewhere. Though it could be unmanaged. But there won't be an `Int32.Operator+`